# How to use QueryNodeVisitor to parse odata $filter for boolean entity type

Tags: c#, parsing, odata

I am wondering how we can use QueryNodeVisitor to parse odata FilterClause for Boolean type. For example,

/api/items?$filter=value eq true

/api/items?$filter=value

From what I tested, both of the above are valid from odata. While the generic QueryNodeVisitor seems to be only working the first case. Any suggestions how to make the second one work too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`QueryNodeVisitor<T>` is a generic class, all the methods are defined to throw `NotImplementedException`.

Would you please share more about "the generic QueryNodeVisitor seems to be only working the first case"?

Beside, I think you can create your own visitor, similar to:

```
public class BooleanVisitor : QueryNodeVisitor<bool>
{
    public override bool Visit(SingleValuePropertyAccessNode propertyNode)
    {
        if (propertyNode == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return propertyNode.TypeReference.IsBoolean();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do have my own QueryNodeVisitor. I think the biggest difference from your example is that in my case "value" is passed in as a SingleValueOpenPropertyAccessNode instead of SingleValuePropertyAccessNode so there is no type information in the Node.